How to enable sorting with Datagrid in Highcharts?
The docs on highcharts.com do not agree with the docs on api.highcharts.com. Two things jump out at me:

The HTML used is div's not table/tr/td
The column options described are completely different

(Also the links to the "API Reference" from the main webpage go to 404's.)
The API docs appear to be the correct ones but unfortunately they don't include the cool sorting options. So my question then is: how do I enable sorting in a Highcharts DataGrid or where can I find an example?


Indeed, the API page is the correct one and unfortunately with current DataGrid version, it's not possible to apply sorting to the data tables. Luckily, in early days of upcoming week, the DataGrid v3 should be officialy relased, with column sorting implemented by default.
